# error: 'current_millis' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, scope, arduino, header, destructor

What you mean my public class variable was not declared in scope did I not just  declare it in the header file >:(

IDE arduino 1.6.12
arduino type uno this should not matter just need it to verify

***timelyCall.cpp***

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "timelyCall.h"
timelyCall::timelyCall() {
  current_millis =  millis();
}

timelyCall::~timelyCall() {
```

*there be errors here /*

```
  delete current_millis;
}

void timelyCall::callEvery(void (&f)(), int ms) {
  if (millis() - current_millis > ms) {
    f();
    current_millis = millis();
  }
}

void setCurrentMillis() {
  current_millis = millis();
}
```

***timelyCall.h***

```
class timelyCall {
  public:
    timelyCall();
    ~timelyCall();
    unsigned long current_millis;
    void callEvery(void (&f)(), int ms);
  };
```

***FullError***

```
Arduino: 1.6.12 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

sketch\timelyCall.cpp: In destructor 'timelyCall::~timelyCall()':

timelyCall.cpp:8: error: type 'long unsigned int' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer

   delete current_millis;

          ^

sketch\timelyCall.cpp: In function 'void setCurrentMillis()':

timelyCall.cpp:19: error: 'current_millis' was not declared in this scope

   current_millis = millis();

   ^

exit status 1
type 'long unsigned int' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: You should `delete` what you `new` (and `delete[]` what you `new[]`). If you haven't dynamically allocated anything with `new` you should not `delete` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not delete `current_mills` in destructor. You should only delete dynamically asigned variables. In other words, if you create object with new you delete it with delete in 1:1 ratio.

As for second error, there is no `setCurrentMills()` function defined inside `timelyCall` class.

You have to modify class definition:

```
class timelyCall {
  public:
    timelyCall();
    ~timelyCall();
    unsigned long current_millis;
    void setCurrentMills();
    void callEvery(void (&f)(), int ms);
  };
```

and then change function definition to be `void timelyCall::setCurrentMills()`.

Also it is a standard to pass a value you want to assign to function `set`. So it would be really beneficial for possible future modification to change this signature to `void setCurrentMills(const unsigned long& mills);` and instead of assigning return value of funcion `mills()` to `current_mills`, call setter with return value of this function like this `object.setCurrentMills(mills());`

Answer (score 1):

Do not delete `current_millis` in destructor, delete only what you create using `new`.